# Spark - Specify schema for flexible keys in a Map

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have some json data in the format:

```
{
    "opp_id": "IxexyLDIIk",
    "id": "IxexyLDIIk",
    "date": 1488465636,
    "imp": {
        "id": "1",
        "banner": [{
            "w": 728,
            "h": 90,
            "pos": 1
        }]

    }
}
```

I would like to create a schema in which the field `imp`, which is a map, can accept any number of values. The issue I see is I cannot do that because inside imp there is a field `banner`, which is an array.

How can one create such schema in spark? that is specify a map that can have any keys and some of those keys have a specific schema.

Ideally I would like a solution in json schema, but scala / pyspark is fine

To clarify, i would like to know if its possible to do:

```
df = spark.read.json(data, schema=THIS_IS_WHAT_I_NEED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
sqlContext.read.
schema(
     ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Some_Case_Class].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
).json(some_json)
```

your case class can look like this code:

```
case class Banner(w : Int, h : Int, pos : Int)
case class Imp(id : Long, Banner : List[Banner])
case class DataSet(opp_id : Long, id :Long, date : Long, imp : Imp)
```

Your reflection could be something like this:

```
ScalaReflection.schemaFor[DataSet].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

You need to have:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
```

I get:

```
res7: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(opp_id,LongType,false), StructField(id,LongType,false), StructField(date,LongType,false), StructField(imp,StructType(StructField(id,LongType,false), StructField(banner,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(w,IntegerType,false), StructField(h,IntegerType,false), StructField(pos,IntegerType,false)),true),true)),true))
```

If you type this into your code in by hand, you might not see some of the Scala Spark Shell nuances - namely that `Seq` needs to be inserted in certain places in order to really see the schema has some series data. To be clearer about where these are, you can issue:

```
res7.printTreeString
root
 |-- opp_id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- date: long (nullable = false)
 |-- imp: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- banner: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- w: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- h: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- pos: integer (nullable = false)
```

Since there are other questions and answers about this `Seq` part, I'm deferring the rest as you now have the tools you probably need.

Comment: Also - There is another similar question / answer that @zero323 answered at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083873/spark-2-0-0-reading-json-data-with-variable-schema?rq=1)

Comment: @codeaperture That link doesnt really anwser what I am looking for, which is a way of defining schemas that allow structs with any number of keys as text (so Map(string, string)), and certain specified keys with a different schema.

Comment: How about `case class Test(m : Map[String, String])`  with `ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Test].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]` to get `StructType(StructField(m,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true))` ?